# SQL Server 2008: Backing up database before running stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that runs once a week that's initiated by the user through the click of a button on our internal website. I'd like to automatically backup the database before the code in the procedure actually runs.

So I've created a separate stored procedure with the following code:

```
DECLARE @Path varchar(50)
SET @Path = '\\1.1.1.1\SQLBackup\DBName' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 10) +'.bak' 

BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO  DISK = @Path WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'DBname-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

I then run the above from my other stored procedure by using

```
EXEC GenerateRenewalBackup
```

The problem is that the application times out on the database backup before it even runs the code in the second stored procedure.

Am I going about this the right way? The database is only 38MB in size. Would it be better to configure the database as a job? Can you run a job from a stored procedure? Any guidance would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The current proc is only run twice a week?  Do you know approximately when it runs?  That is, "every tuesday & thursday at around 7" or something?  Or is it fairly random?

Comment: It's usually every Thursday at 4:30pm but that's not concrete. It's always on Thursday but the user can kick it off at whatever time they want.

Comment: So it looks like sp_startjob runs asynchronously. Am I better to execute a sp that calls sp_startjob then wait for the return code (0 for success) and then call the other stored procedure to actually run the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add a [`WITH COPY_ONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx) clause to your backup so that it does not interfere with a ordinary maintenance backup chain (If this *is* your backup chain, then is wrong anyway and you need a proper [maintenance plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953.aspx) in place).

Next, you can either:

- Increase the CommandTimeout on your application so that it waits until the procedure finishes (default times out in 30 seconds).
- Make the button create/start an SQL Agent job right away instead of running the procedure.
- Use [asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/).

Which one is the right choice, depends on many factors only you know. My bet would be that this should be a regular scheduled job and there should be no user interaction, but without understanding the business process driving this is impossible to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SQL Agent job:.

1. First step, Backup database.
2. Second Step, run your stored procedure
3. Define a schedule for job to be run.

Comment: I can't define the schedule as it needs to be kicked off by the user. But it's always on a Thursday and generally around 4:30pm

Comment: @Mike: that sounds like a schedule!

Answer (score 1):

> Can you run a job from a stored
>   procedure?

Yes you can, use [sp_startjob](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) to start a job or just schedule the job to run once a day

Answer (score 1):

Run a full backup the night before (why not on such a small db) and then only a differential or transaction log backup before the proc runs.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is probably fine, but it does not make sense for this to be a synchronous operation in the web app.  Fire the the SP off asynchronously then do something like send the user an email to tell them their action has completed.